# dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project that i am working on. I have a navbar at the top and in the navbar i have a dropdown menu that does not work. I've been ignoring the problem for a while but now i need things in the dropdown menu. I have been slowly taking things out of my project trying to find the cause. I am now at a point where i have replaced my navbar, (located in my header file) with the [bootstrap demo one](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default).

This is my _header.html.erb  (pretty much the same as bootstrap, except for the head tag)

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
  </script>

</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

This is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all","data-turbolinks-track" => true %>

    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true%> 
    <%= javascript_include_tag "http://localhost:9292/faye.js"%> 
    <%= javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js" %>    
    <%= include_gon %>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" style = "width: 100%; padding: 0px">
      <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The page loads but when i click on "dropdown" nothing happens. I'm stumped, does anyone have any ideas?? I have also been disecting my code looking for syntax errors and haven't found any. Since i am still getting the same error with bootstraps code it seems unlikely that a syntax error is the cause.

Comment: can you show us the CSS part or reproduce this in fiddle?

Comment: where is your bootstrap.js..?

Comment: the bootstrap.js is located in app>assets>javascript and as for the css. The css is bootstrap. like 4000 lines. I just tried it in fiddle and the result was not so great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at your partial `_header.hml.erb` and noticed your have a `head tag` inside it. You should remove it.

If you look at your `application.html.erb` layout you **already have a head tag** there and you are **rendering that _header.html.erb partial inside your body tag**.

You have

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true%>
```

which links your javascript to **assets/javascript/application.js**. If you need to write any javascript in your project then that is the place to write it or you could make any *new js file inside assets/javascript and then require that file inside your application.js file*

You should remove this

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
  </script>
</head>
```

from your partial and instead simply write in your application.js:

```
$(document).on("click",".dropdown-toggle",function(){
  $(this).dropdown();
});
```

I have used on function used to *incorporate for turbolinks*

Comment: I added 
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap", "data-turbolinks-track" => true%> and now the dropdowns show. Thanks. so do i have to do a line like that for all my javascript files?

Comment: yeah you should write all your js inside assets/javascript folder. Make separate files for your important js functions or make just a single if you don't have enough js in your project and then require that file inside application.js file. For more information read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)